# Expansion of Elementary Symmetric Functions

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, generating-functions, symmetric-polynomials

Let
$$e_k(X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n)=\sum_{1\le i_1<i_2<\dots<i_k\le n}X_{i_1}X_{i_2}\dots X_{i_k}$$
be the elementary symmetric function of degree $k$ and
$$p_k(X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n)=\sum_{1\le i\le n}X_{i}^k$$
be the power sum symmetric function of degree $k$. Is there any way to write
$$e_1^n=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}(a_i\cdot e_i +b_j\cdot p_j +c_{i,j}\cdot e_i \cdot p_j)$$
That is, to write $e_1^n$ as the sum of various $e_i$'s, $p_j$'s, and their products. I am also interested in any well known formulae for $e_1^n$, even if they don't match the form above. Similar formulae would be [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), one of which being
$$e_k=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i-1}e_{k-i}\cdot p_i$$
Testing this out we have 
$$\begin{gather}
e_1(X_1)=e_1 \\
e_1(X_1,X_2)^2=p_2+2e_2 \\
e_1(X_1,X_2,X_3)^3=e_1p_2+2e_2p_1 \\
\vdots
\end{gather}$$